# I need to iterate a while loop using if statements

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

Im writing a program in python that creates a function which paths a white line right or down in an array depending on the greater value of the adjacent random number. I have been emailing my professor and I think I have written it properly. The code is not running through enough iterations to draw the line of 1's through the Array.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

def im(A):
i=0;
j=0;
S=A.shape
while i<S[0] and j<S[1]:
    if (A[i+1,j]>A[i,j+1]):
        A[i+1,j]=1;
        i=i+1;
    else:
       A[i,j+1]=1;
       j=j+1;
       return A
A=np.random.rand(10,10)*0.5
A=im(A)
figure(1), imshow(A,cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Which lines are in the function, which are after it?

Comment: Python does not need lines terminated with semi-colons and they are not normally used for single-line statements (as a matter of style).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your return statement is in the `else` section. It should be after the while loop. You also need to check one ahead of i and j in the loop condition.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

def im(A):
    A[0][0] = 1
    i=0;
    j=0;
    S=A.shape
    while i+1<S[0] and j+1<S[1]:
        if (A[i+1,j]>A[i,j+1]):
            A[i+1,j]=1;
            i=i+1;
        else:
           A[i,j+1]=1;
           j=j+1;
    return A

A=np.random.rand(10,10)*0.5
A=im(A)
print(A)
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much!! Sorry for the indentation problems this was my first question on this forum, but your critique was exactly what I needed.